# running script containing sudo in cron

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, sudo

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
      sleep 30;
    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
fi
```

I need to run above script in cron. Will it execute in cron without password?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It will only execute without needing a password prompt if you are running it from root's crontab or if you have specifically given these password-less rights to the user in the `sudo` configuration file, editable through the command `visudo`.

Comment: [A duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/478690/running-script-containing-sudo-in-cron) and [another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869523/running-script-containing-sudo-in-cron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `sudo` not to require a password:

1. Make `/var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym` executable:

   ```
   $ chmod a+x /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym
   ```
2. Replace in your script:

   ```
   sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server
   ```

   with:

   ```
   sudo /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server
   ```
3. Use `visudo` to add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

   ```
   <user who runs the cronjob> ALL = NOPASSWD:/path/to/xargs [-0-9 a-z]*, /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym [-0-9 a-z]*
   ```

Comment: The user will also need to give password-less rights to `xargs` to kill the program as the script stands.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather lay out the script similar to:

```
#!/bin/sh
read value < /path/to/man.txt

if [ "$value" = "true" ]; then
    pkill -u root '^sym$' && sleep 30
    sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server
fi
```

Since you want to run every command as root anyway, put it in root's crontab. If you don't need to run anything as root, don't. If you actually need to run it via `sudo` through specifically configured rights for certain applications, bring back `sudo`, but note that you also will need specifically configured rights to kill the program (unless it has an equivalent to a `--kill` switch).

I stripped the `echo`s since unnecessary print statements in a crontab will just clutter logs. You could implement a logging mechanism within the script if its necessary.